# How to access method of dynamically loaded com?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, ocx, activexobject

For my application i have to dynamically load an .ocx file. I can do this by the following code

```
    private void InitializeComponent(string strProgId)
    {
        ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(AxForm));

        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(strProgId, true);
        m_axCtrl = new AxControl(type.GUID.ToString());

        ((ISupportInitialize)(m_axCtrl)).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();

        m_axCtrl.Enabled = true;
        m_axCtrl.Name = "axCtrl";
        m_axCtrl.TabIndex = 0;

        Controls.Add(m_axCtrl);

        Name = "AxForm";
        ((ISupportInitialize)(m_axCtrl)).EndInit();
        Resize += new EventHandler(AxForm_Resize);
        ResumeLayout(false);
        OnResize();
        Show();
    }
```

But my next problem is i don't how to access the properties and methods of the dynamically loaded control. How can i achieve this? Please help me

Comment: Pretty important to document your source, you have to mention that you copied this from a Codeproject.com article.  Saves everybody a lot of time trying to figure out where the heck these classes come from.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the '[dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd264736.aspx)' pseudo-type keyword. It will never fail at compile time, only at runtime (so you have to define calls carefully so they match the underlying definition) like this (I suppose you have 2 methods on the OCX):

```
dynamic ocx = m_axCtrl.GetOcx();
ocx.DoThis(arg1, arg2);
ocx.DoThat();
```

Comment: It works. But how can i register an event according to your suggestion?

Comment: ocx.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);

Comment: In the MyEventHandler, what will be the types of event arguments?

Comment: Currently i used object as type for arguments. But Some events doesn't fire. Please see my Event handler             
        public void MyEventHandler(object sender, object e)
        {

        }

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Reflection.

For instance:
Let's say that you have a method with the name LoadFile.

then:

```
m_axCtrl.GetOcx().GetType().InvokeMember("LoadFile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, m_axCtrl.GetOcx(), new object[1] { path });
```

Comment: How can i register an event using this approach

Comment: Subscribing to an Event using Reflection is a tricky task. I hope this example will explain everything. http://pastebin.com/mwvcxUDf